# None of my Rails 5 assets are minifying in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 5.0.0.1 app on Heroku and when I hit the developer console in Chrome and open up the CSS and JS files I can see that neither of them have been minified. This was first brought to my attention after completing a Google speed test.

This is what some of my setup looks like...

`application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require trix
//= require_tree .
```

`application.scss`

```
//Import bootstrap-sprockets
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";


// Import cerulean variables
@import "bootswatch/flatly/variables";

// Then bootstrap itself
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";

// Bootstrap body padding for fixed navbar
/*body { padding-top: 60px; }*/

// And finally bootswatch style itself
@import "bootswatch/flatly/bootswatch";

// Whatever application styles you have go last
@import "overrides";
@import "trip";
```

I'm using the following gems:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'bootswatch-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-social-rails'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
```

And I have the following options set in `production.rb`

```
# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = false
```

I've precompiled and cleaned the assets and I've even bumped the assets version using

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.1'
```

I even nuked hell out of my assets folder using `rake assets:clobber`

Really at a loss now as to why none of these assets are minifying. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When you run `rake assets:precompile` locally, are the outputted assets minified? You'll want to temporarily set your development.rb settings to the same as production, in order to properly test this.

Comment: Nope. Still no minification on css or js files when I do this

Comment: Are your assets being compiled into `application.css/application.js` files like you expect? Have you tried setting `config.assets.debug = false`? Is this new behavior since you upgraded to Rails 5?

Comment: Yes, they're being compiled into `application.css/application.js` and also `applicaiton.css.gz and application.js.gz`. I've just tried setting `config.assets.debug = false` but this didn't change anything. This isn't new behaviour since upgrading. Something else strange - if I look on GitHub this project is apparently 64% CSS, which is significantly higher than all my other Rails projects

Comment: that sounds like you might have checked in compiled assets into Git, within your public/assets folder. Does your GitHub repository have a `public/assets` folder with files within?

Comment: Yeah it;s packed full. Guessing it's not supposed to be..?

Comment: Your issue might be that those assets are being used instead of the ones that are built during the Heroku deploy. I'd suggest removing all of those assets (`git rm -r public/assets`) and deploy again. Be prepared to rollback to the previous version if this breaks your production site, though!

Comment: Yeah, nailed it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Cool! I summarized the above into an answer, if you'd like to mark it accepted for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the conclusion from my and OP's comments on the main post, the issue was not that minification isn't working, but that the minified assets weren't being used. This is because the assets at one point had been precompiled into `public/assets` and checked into Git; the public, unminified assets then took precedence over the minified assets when being served.

The solution, then, was to remove those artifacts from Git:

```
git rm -r public/assets
```

Checking precompiled assets into version control is generally discouraged, although it depends on your deployment system. With Heroku, there's usually no need. See [Do you add public/assets in version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561043/do-you-add-public-assets-in-version-control) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

What's your Gemfile look like?  Is there a JavaScript runner for the uglifier?  `therubyracer` is often used, and I have been fairly happy with [`mini_racer`](https://github.com/discourse/mini_racer) and its enhanced performance.

In your Gemfile:

```ruby
gem 'mini_racer'
```

Then run `bundle install` and commit.